# Understanding multiple values in a single cell of a truth table (P v ~Q) as (1 1 0 1) when P and Q are 1

Tags: logic, propositions

This might seem basic to most here but I am struggling with a truth table for a disjunct. As I am looking at it further, I actually think the issue I am struggling with how to interpret truth values of negations.

The proposition is as follows: P v ~Q

The truth table goes

**P Q** --------P   V   ~   Q

**1 1**---------       1    1   0   1

**1 0**---------       1    1   1   0

**0 1**---------       0    0   0   1

**0 0**---------       0    1   1   0

I'm trying to see if I understand this correctly. In row 1 when Q is said to be true, does that mean 'Q' in isolation is true and so in the phrase '~ Q' the negation is now false? Which would mean '~ Q' is in effect just 'Q'? And the negation gets a false truth value?

And so the reason the (inclusive) disjunct holds in row 1 is because the proposition equals "P (true) or Q (true)" and since a disjunct states that one or both components of its proposition are true, and in this case both are, the disjunct holds?

Is that how row 3 is to be explained? P is not true, Q is. But (true) Q is negated, making it an untrue statement. And so the proposition is saying "(untrue) P or (untrue) Q". So in effect it is neither, and thus the disjunct doesn't hold (as it has to be one or both).

Another one I am struggling with is ~E ^ D

**E D** -------- ~  E   ^   D

**1 1**----------       0   1   0   1

**1 0**----------       0   1   0   0

**0 1**----------       1   0   1   1

**0 0**----------         1 0   0   0

If E is true, that means its negation is not? And so in ~E ^ D, we have both E and D as true, and so the conjunct operator should have a positive truth value.. no?

Comment: What are the 4-tuples on the right? If P and Q are both 1, then P v Q is 1. Not "1101". I don't follow your notation.

Comment: The textbook I am using says, in the case of P v ~Q, if both  P and Q are true, then P gets a positive truth value, Q gets a positive truth value, its negation gets a negative one, and the disjunct gets a positive one.

P = 1. Q = 1. ~ = 0. v = 1

Comment: If a sentence is true (or ‘1’), then the sentence’s negation is false (or ‘0’). A disjunction is 1 as long as one disjunct is 1. In **P v ~Q**, the disjuncts are **P** and **~Q**, rather than **P** and **Q**! Also, when **Q** is 0, **~Q** is 1. **P v ~Q** is then also 1. By contrast, if **Q** is 1, **~Q** is 0. **P v ~Q** is then also 0, *unless* **P** is 1. That’s what happens in the first row: **~Q** is 0 (because **Q** is 1), but **P** is 1; so one disjunct is 1; so the disjunction is 1. In the third row, both **P** and **~Q** are 0, whence the disjunction is also 0.

Comment: For conjunction: “If E is true, that means its negation is not?” Yes. “And so in ~E ^ D, we have both E and D as true” If both **E** and **D** are 1, then **~E** is 0, as you said. Yet if **~E** is 0, then **~E^D** is also 0 because conjunction is 1 only if both conjuncts are 1. (The conjuncts are **~E** and **D**, rather than **E** and **D**.)

Comment: @MarkOxford could you help me understand how the truth table is built? I think I am understanding it, albeit informally. For the third row of the first example, the disjunction is false because the proposition is "P (or) not-Q." So if Q is 1, then not-Q is 0. So, P is 0 and ~Q is 0. I think that's where I was going wrong? Not understanding that the variable and its operator are considered whole?

But why is it that the truth value of the variable is given primacy, yet we 'consider' the variable always with its operator? I hope that question makes sense? Not enough characters to elaborate.

Comment: Remember that truth tables aren’t built left to right, but from the inside outwards, as it were. We have a disjunction, of the form φ∨ψ. Before we can assign a truth value to ‘∨’, we must first assign values to φ and ψ. As φ=P, we just copy over the value for P. However, ψ is itself complex: ψ=¬Q, so ψ is of the form ¬χ. Once again, before we can assign a truth value to ‘¬’, we must assign a value to χ. Since χ=Q, we copy over the value for Q. Your logic book should discuss the concept of the **main** connective. The main connective is always the **last** item to be assigned a truth value.

Answer (score 2):

You begin with the literals.

```
 (P v (~ Q))     ((~ E) ^ D)
 (1   (  1))     ((  1)   1)
 (1   (  0))     ((  1)   0)
 (0   (  1))     ((  0)   1)
 (0   (  0))     ((  0)   1)
```

Then the negation of Q, E

```
       ~ *         ~ *
 (P v (~ Q))     ((~ E) ^ D)
 (1   (0 1))     ((0 1)   1)
 (1   (1 0))     ((0 1)   0)
 (0   (0 1))     ((1 0)   0)
 (0   (1 0))     ((1 0)   0)
```

Finally the disjunction of P and the negation, the conjunction of D and the negation

```
  * v  *           *    ^ *
 (P v (~ Q))     ((~ E) ^ D)
 (1 1 (0 1))     ((0 1) 0 1)
 (1 1 (1 0))     ((0 1) 0 0)
 (0 0 (0 1))     ((1 0) 1 1)
 (0 1 (1 0))     ((1 0) 0 0)
```

Alternatively

```
 P : Q | ~Q : Pv~Q
 1 : 1 | 0  :  1
 1 : 0 | 1  :  1
 0 : 1 | 0  :  0
 0 : 0 | 1  :  1

 E : D | ~E : ~E^D
 1 : 1 | 0  :   0
 1 : 0 | 0  :   0
 0 : 1 | 1  :   1
 0 : 0 | 1  :   0
```

Answer (score 2):

There's basically two notations for doing truth-tables. The one you're using is the harder one, so it might be best to look at how it would look with the easier one and then transition to the harder one.

The easier one uses the following format:

1. Columns for each variable
2. Columns for helper rows
3. Columns for the premises
4. A column for the conclusion

(In the case of what you're doing we haven't gotten so far as a conclusion.

For P v ~Q, we have:

1. The variables P and Q
2. The helper row ~Q
3. The premise row P v ~ Q

   ```
   P |  Q  | ~Q | P v ~Q 
   1 |  1  |  0 |   1
   1 |  0  |  1 |   1
   0 |  1  |  0 |   0
   0 |  0  |  1 |   1
   ```

The more advanced version does the same thing but puts the helper rows in situ with spacing (~Q's value is placed directly under ~Q *inside* the premise).

Your second example is broadly similar:

1. The variables E and D
2. The helper row ~E
3. The output ~E ^ D

   ```
   E |  D  | ~E | ~E ^ D 
   1 |  1  |  0 |    0
   1 |  0  |  0 |    0
   0 |  1  |  1 |    1
   0 |  0  |  1 |    0
   ```

Done the other way:

pedantic first intermediate step:

```
    E |  D  |  ~E ^ D 
    1 |  1  |  _1 _ 1
    1 |  0  |  _1 _ 0 
    0 |  1  |  _0 _ 1
    0 |  0  |  _0 _ 0
```

(after this I will forgo writing the value E itself there just to make it less painful on the eyes).

intermediate step looks like this:

```
    E |  D  |  ~E ^ D 
    1 |  1  |  0  _ 1
    1 |  0  |  0  _ 0 
    0 |  1  |  1  _ 1
    0 |  0  |  1  _ 0
```

final product looks like this:

```
    E |  D  | ~E ^ D 
    1 |  1  |  0 0 1
    1 |  0  |  0 0 0 
    0 |  1  |  1 1 1
    0 |  0  |  1 0 0
```

Simply put, once you get used to it, the condensed format is easier to do, but until you understand the method, the multiple values in what looks like a single column thing is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with your notation. Here is the standard presentation for the truth table for P v ~Q : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+p+or+not+q

The first line tells us that if P is true and Q is true, then P v ~Q is true.

The second line tells us that if P is true and Q is false, then P v ~Q is true.

The third line tells us that if P is false and Q is true, then P v ~Q is false.

The fourth line tells us that if P is false and Q is false, then P v ~Q is true.